# Parent 100% viewport height, one child fixed height and another takes remaining

Tags: css

I'm trying to style a 100% viewport height page with a fixed height navigation at the top and a body below it that should take the remaining height.

*html*

```
<div class="chat">
  <nav>
    <a>Chat</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>Log In</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      Users
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div>
        Messages
      </div>
      <div>
        Input
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*css*

```
.chat {
  height: 100vh;
}
.row {
  background-color: #eceeef;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Chat is taking 100% viewport height, child nav is taking some fixed height and child row is taking 100% of it's parent so the result is a row with 100% viewport height. The page ends up to be the viewport height plus the nav height, activating scroll. I need that row to take the viewport height minus the nav height, i.e remaining height in chat after nav.

Comment: is nav height known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming nav height is 50px, we can calculate height of remain space using css function `calc`:

```css
.chat {
  height: 100vh;
}
nav {
  height: 50px;
}
.row {
  background-color: #eceeef;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

assuming nav is absolutely positioned (in this case it will be overlap row) and row top edge will stand behind nav, we need to move down row content with `padding-top: 50px;`

```css
.chat {
  height: 100vh;
}
nav {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.row {
  background-color: #eceeef;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```